# C++ Qt sql lite database connection issue

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, qt5

The following code is used by me to connect to a database using Qt IDE. And if it successfully connects to the database `Connected to db` is printed on a label. But the issue is if I even given a wrong database path it returns `Connected to db` on the label how can i correct this issue?

```
QSqlDatabase  mydb= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mydb.setDatabaseName("x");
if(!mydb.open()){
    ui->label->setText("Failed to open the db");
}
else{
    ui->label->setText("Connected to db");
}
```

Even though in the above code i put "x" which is not a valid database  path I get "Connected to db' in the label when I run the program!

How can i correct this issue?

Comment: Sqlite is a particular database, if the database does not exist, it will create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt uses as SQLite backend uses the [`sqlite`](https://www.sqlite.org) library, so you will use one of the functions to open the database:

```
int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
int sqlite3_open16(
  const void *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-16) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
int sqlite3_open_v2(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb,         /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
  int flags,              /* Flags */
  const char *zVfs        /* Name of VFS module to use */
);
```

According to the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open):

> These routines open an SQLite database file as specified by the
>   filename argument. The filename argument is interpreted as UTF-8 for
>   sqlite3_open() and sqlite3_open_v2() and as UTF-16 in the native byte
>   order for sqlite3_open16(). A database connection handle is usually
>   returned in *ppDb, even if an error occurs. **The only exception is that
>   if SQLite is unable to allocate memory to hold the sqlite3 object**, a
>   NULL will be written into *ppDb instead of a pointer to the sqlite3
>   object. **If the database is opened (and/or created) successfully, then
>   SQLITE_OK** is returned. Otherwise an error code is returned. The
>   sqlite3_errmsg() or sqlite3_errmsg16() routines can be used to obtain
>   an English language description of the error following a failure of
>   any of the sqlite3_open() routines.

From which we conclude that if the database does not exist this will create it, it will only generate the error in creating it if there are problems to allocate memory.